# Python datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp() Bug

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime-format

python version: 2.7.12

When I use the `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` function to transfer the float timestamp to the date format, I found this function can transfer the two different timestamps into the same date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta4E7.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or error messages, post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue in python 3.6. I see datetime1 = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 3, 5, 2, 28), datetime2 = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 3, 6, 2, 28).

Comment: Without your actual code and input, it's hard to be sure, but are you giving it a timestamp in the middle of a DST transition and another timestamp an hour earlier/later? If so, that's not a bug, that's how DST works. (If that's not acceptable for your application, you probably wanted UTC rather than local times somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you. My code is date_1=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1383454948.0), date_2=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1383458548.0). Both return the same date, i.e., datetime.datetime(2013,11,3,1,2,28).

Comment: My python version is 2.7.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you're somewhere in the southern hemisphere, and your country ended Daylight Saving Time this weekend.

In my timezone (in the northern hemisphere), DST ends on 4 November this year, so:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 1, 15).timestamp()
1541319300.0
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1541319300.0)
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 1, 15)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1541319300.0+3600)
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 1, 15)
```

How could that be right? Well, 4 November 2018 01:15 happens twice. It happens, and then at 02:00, we set our clocks back an hour, so it happens again. But the two 01:15s have different timestamps—we're not actually going back in time (plus, we only set our clocks back at the first 02:00, not every 02:00, or we'd be stuck in that hour for the rest of our lives).

---

This is how DST works, and software that deals with local times has to deal with it.

If your software doesn't have to deal with local times, of course, you should be using UTC instead, which doesn't have DST (and also doesn't give different answers if you run your script on a cloud server located 3000km away, and so on).

---

It's also worth pointing out that this is one of the many things that have been improved since Python 2.7. If I run the same thing in 3.6, I'll see this for the second one:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 1, 15, fold=1)
```

That `fold` is a value that I can check to see which 01:15 it really is, and that I can pass into the constructor to specify which 01:15 I want. Getting/specifying the same information in earlier versions requires some very clumsy extra work.